# Проблема с Router + UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-hook

Ситуация такая у меня есть апи(method GET) который вызывается через Context, прописал state, reducer там всё ок. Вызываю данную функцию через useEffect и она вызывается. Проблема в том, что в networke при перезагрузке страницы функция с апи вызывается 5 раз одна и та же. прочекал по локам ошибка в Router. А именно в  Подскажите как быть с данной ошибкой? парюсь уже несколько дней над этим

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

```
    <BrowserRouter history={history}>
      <GuardProvider guards={[requireLogin]} loading={Loading} error={NotFoundPage}>
        {children(
          <Switch>
            <GuardedRoute
              path="/register"
              exact
              component={() => AuthContainer({children: RegisterPage()})}
              meta={{ auth: false }}
            />
            <GuardedRoute path="/login" exact component={() => AuthContainer({children: AuthPage()})} meta={{ auth: false }}
            />
            <GuardedRoute path="/pro" exact component={() => DefaultContainer({children: ProPage(), classes: 'page-pro'})} meta={{ auth: true }} />``

            <GuardedRoute path="/" exact component={() => DefaultContainer({children: TaskListPage()})} meta={{ auth: true }} />
            <GuardedRoute path="/task/:id" exact component={() => DefaultContainer({children: TaskInfoPage()})} meta={{ auth: true }} />
            <GuardedRoute path="/history" exact component={() => DefaultContainer({children:HistoryPage()})} meta={{ auth: true }} />
            <GuardedRoute path="*" component={() => DefaultContainer({children: NotFoundPage()})} />
          </Switch>
        )}
      </GuardProvider>
      <Tabbar/>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: `useEffect(() => {fetchStories()},[])`

`const {fetchStories} = useContext(HistoryContext);`

Comment: А если использоваться просто Router то будет указывать на ошибку в children is not a function перед <Switch>

Comment: Как я понял по логике. У меня каким-то образом компонент, где выводятся данные пересоздается 5 раз. Я это проверил по console.log(). Он так же как и функция вызывается 5 раз. Может Вы сталкивались с данной проблемой, о том, что компонент пересоздается несколько раз, а не один раз?

Comment: А что Вам показать? Layout или DefaultContainer. Просто проект по себе разделено на несколько components и pages. И просто выгрузить его будет сложновато

Comment: Весь код, в котором, по вашему мнению, скрыта ошибка. Компонент, вызывающий API 5 раз. Если API вызывается 5 раз. Какой-то код должен вызывать его 5 раз. Он не будет вызван автоматически.

Comment: Пока переписывал, чтобы Вам показать нашёл ошибку. Ошибка заключалась в, то что в файле Router, который прописал. Вызывал функцию через UseEffect, которая брала инфу о юзере. Я её перенёс в DefaultContainer и всё заработало, и больше не вызывается API 5 раз